# cannot be assigned to -- it is read only - C#

Tags: c#

```
public struct Osoba{
    public string nazwisko;
    [...]
}

for (int k = 0; k < l; k++)
            {
                dlugosc = osoba[k].nazwisko.Length;
                [...]
                if (c[0] == 's' && c[1] == 'k' && c[2] == 'i')
                {
                    osoba[k].nazwisko[dlugosc - 3] = '*';
                    osoba[k].nazwisko[dlugosc - 2] = '*';
                    osoba[k].nazwisko[dlugosc - 1] = '*';
                }
            }
```

Hello there, I keep trying to replace 3 last letters of string, but i get this error:

> Property or indexer 'string.this[int]' cannot be assigned to -- it is
>   read only\

I tried to google it, the solution was mostly adding getters and setters (i've yet to learn about it) but it didn't help me. Why can't I modify my string even thought i set everything as public?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings are immutable in .NET. It's quite unclear what you are trying to achieve but if you want to directly manipulate the contents you could use a char array instead:

```
public struct Osoba
{
    public char[] nazwisko;

    [...]
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`Strings` are *immutable*.You can't change a string after you created it.You need to create a new string and assign it back:

```
osoba[k].nazwisko = osoba[k].nazwisko.Substring(0, dlugosc - 3) + "***";
```